# Problem In Running easy_install.exe under Windows

Tags: python

I am running Python under windows.

I face no problem in installing pysqlite package.

```
C:\>c:\Python26\Scripts\easy_install.exe pysqlite
Searching for pysqlite
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pysqlite/
........
Download error: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://initd.org/tracker/pysqlite/wiki/PysqliteDownloads
........
Best match: pysqlite 2.5.6
Downloading http://pysqlite.googlecode.com/files/pysqlite-2.5.6.win32-py2.6.exe
Processing pysqlite-2.5.6.win32-py2.6.exe
WARNING: can't process DATA/pysqlite2-doc/default.css
WARNING: can't process DATA/pysqlite2-doc/docutils.css
WARNING: can't process DATA/pysqlite2-doc/install-source.txt
creating 'c:\docume~1\yan-ch~1.che\locals~1\temp\easy_install-5wz15q\pysqlite-2.5.6-py2.6-win32.egg' and adding 'c:\docume~1\ya
n-ch~1.che\locals~1\temp\easy_install-5wz15q\pysqlite-2.5.6-py2.6-win32.egg.tmp' to it
Moving pysqlite-2.5.6-py2.6-win32.egg to c:\python26\lib\site-packages
Adding pysqlite 2.5.6 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\python26\lib\site-packages\pysqlite-2.5.6-py2.6-win32.egg
Processing dependencies for pysqlite
Finished processing dependencies for pysqlite
```

However, I fail to install psycopg

```
C:\>c:\Python26\Scripts\easy_install.exe psycopg
Searching for psycopg
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/psycopg/
Reading http://initd.org/projects/psycopg1
Best match: psycopg 1.1.21
Downloading http://initd.org/pub/software/psycopg/psycopg-1.1.21.tar.gz
Processing psycopg-1.1.21.tar.gz
error: Couldn't find a setup script in c:\docume~1\yan-ch~1.che\locals~1\temp\easy_install-recnw8\psycopg-1.1.21.tar.gz
```

Is there other alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The psycopg PyPi posting does not contain a pre-built w32 installer that easy_install can use nor could it find a way to build from source.

Here are some [pre-built versions of the psycopg module](http://stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/).

Answer (score 0):

easy_install only knows how to install modules distributed with the Python standard distribution and packaging solution called distutils. Psycopg is not. Psycopg is instead installed with the so called CMMI dance: configure/make/make install. Doing that on Windows is tricky, hence, you need to download a precompiled version, see Christians answer.